# Docker bridge network error :- services.catalog.api.networks must be a list

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

```
I have just started learning docker . This is my docker-compose.yml file . It shows the following error   "services.catalog.api.networks must be a list" When I docker compose up
```

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  testnetwork:
    driver: bridge 


services:
  orderdb:
    image: mongo

  catalogdb:
    image: mongo  
    
  orderapi:
    image: orderapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: OrderApi/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5243:5243
    networks:
      testnetwork 



  catalog.api:
    image: farhanpatel/catalogapi
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogdb:27017"      
    depends_on: 
      - catalogdb  
    ports:
      - "5116:5116"  
    networks:
      testnetwork     

volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

I want to connect both orderapi and catalogapi through docker bridge  network.

I have created a bridge network named testnetwork and used it in above docker-compose.yml .

Could someone explain how should I connect both the images

Answer (score 0):

You should separate app form Mongodb. My example docker-compose(node.js,MongoDB)

```
version: "3"
services:
  nodeapp:
    container_name: nodeapp
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "4500:4500"
    links:
      - mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: mongodb:27017
    networks:
      - node-webapp-network
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:6.0
    volumes:
      - ~/mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=your_user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=your_password
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
    networks:
      - node-webapp-network
networks:
  node-webapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

command

```
docker network ls
```

to list networks

And to inspect

```
docker inspect testnetwork
```

will give you

```
[
    {
        "Name": "testnetwork",
        "Id": "259b9fd2d442984f142849152ac68eabd481c2ed0d24168080edace7930c5302",
        "Created": "2022-05-01T07:45:29.549723985+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.24.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.24.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

You should also read some Docker books or courses where you have step by step explained.

Answer (score 0):

You should just delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file.  Compose on its own creates a network named `default` and attaches containers to it, and this is enough for all standard Docker networking functionality to work.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  orderdb:
    image: mongo
  orderapi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: OrderApi/Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: orderdb
    ports:
      - 5243:5243
# no networks: at all
```

If you do have `networks:`, a container can be attached to multiple networks, and so the value of the per-container `networks:` needs to be a YAML list.  Usually this means putting `-`  at the front of the line (the space is important).  You need to do this for *all* of your containers; in the example as you've shown it, the API servers would be on `testnetwork` but the databases still on the `default` network.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
networks:            # <-- added from previous example
  testnetwork:       # <-- (or you can safely delete _all_ of these)
services:
  orderdb:
    image: mongo
    networks:        # <--
      - testnetwork  # <--
  orderapi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: OrderApi/Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: orderdb
    ports:
      - 5243:5243
    networks:        # <--
      - testnetwork  # <--
#     ^^ note YAML list marker
```